# Как осуществить поиск похожего текста в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, текст, выборка

Дано: таблица с полями `id` и `txt`, где `txt` - небольшая статья, пост или комментарий, содержащий HTML, примерный объем записи - 2-10 кб, всего записей 100к-1млн.

Нужно извлечь группы записей, в которых текст *приблизительно* похож, т.е. совпадать процентов на 80-90, т.к. идентично равных строк в БД нет.

Позволяют ли существующие механизмы БД осуществить такую выборку, и как это сделать?

UPD: (очень близко) есть ли аналог пхп-шного `similar_text()` в mysql? Скорость выполнения запроса не имеет значение.

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/488

Answer (score 2):

Как было сказано выше, можно попробовать расстояние Левенштейна. Еще один пример реализации для mysql тут: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=552

Можно сделать адаптированный вариант с этого примера:

```
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein( s1 text, s2 text ) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, i, j, c, c_temp, cost INT; 
    DECLARE s1_char CHAR; 
    -- max strlen=255 
    DECLARE cv0, cv1 VARBINARY(10240); 
    SET s1_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s1), s2_len = CHAR_LENGTH(s2), cv1 = 0x00, j = 1, i = 1, c = 0; 
    IF s1 = s2 THEN 
      RETURN 0; 
    ELSEIF s1_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s2_len; 
    ELSEIF s2_len = 0 THEN 
      RETURN s1_len; 
    ELSE 
      WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
        SET cv1 = CONCAT(cv1, UNHEX(HEX(j))), j = j + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
      WHILE i <= s1_len DO 
        SET s1_char = SUBSTRING(s1, i, 1), c = i, cv0 = UNHEX(HEX(i)), j = 1; 
        WHILE j <= s2_len DO 
          SET c = c + 1; 
          IF s1_char = SUBSTRING(s2, j, 1) THEN  
            SET cost = 0; ELSE SET cost = 1; 
          END IF; 
          SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j, 1)), 16, 10) + cost; 
          IF c > c_temp THEN SET c = c_temp; END IF; 
            SET c_temp = CONV(HEX(SUBSTRING(cv1, j+1, 1)), 16, 10) + 1; 
            IF c > c_temp THEN  
              SET c = c_temp;  
            END IF; 
            SET cv0 = CONCAT(cv0, UNHEX(HEX(c))), j = j + 1; 
        END WHILE; 
        SET cv1 = cv0, i = i + 1; 
      END WHILE; 
    END IF; 
    RETURN c; 
  END; 

CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein_ratio( s1 text, s2 text ) 
  RETURNS INT 
  DETERMINISTIC 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE s1_len, s2_len, max_len INT; 
    SET s1_len = LENGTH(s1), s2_len = LENGTH(s2); 
    IF s1_len > s2_len THEN  
      SET max_len = s1_len;  
    ELSE  
      SET max_len = s2_len;  
    END IF; 
    RETURN ROUND((1 - LEVENSHTEIN(s1, s2) / max_len) * 100); 
  END;
```

Выбрать попарно похожие строки так:

```
select t1.id, t1.txt, t2.id, t2.txt
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t2.id <> t1.id and levenshtein_ratio(t1.txt, t2.txt) > 80
```

Как разбить результат выборки на группы, придется подумать.

По работе, если кратко, то алгоритм считает количество замен/добавлений символов в текст, чтобы получить полностью схожие записи. Но главная проблема - алгоритм осуществляет посимволный перебор, что является довольно затратным.
А теперь если учесть, что длина текста 2-10 кб и до 1 млн. записей, то база будет просто умирать от такой "аналитики" (а не забывайте, что главная задача базы - осуществлять хранение и доступ к данным, но никак не реализовывать сложные вычислительные алгоритмы).

Поэтому я бы рекомендовал, пока не поздно, подумать над тем, чтобы вынести реализацию за пределы базы. Можно найти множество "быстрых" реализации вычисления расстояния Левенштейна практически на всех языках. При реализации предложил бы делать какую-то предварительную фильтрацию, например по длине текста, т.е. если длина не совпадает на 80%, то сравнение даже не проводить, т.к. даже на производительных машинах сравнение таких объемов текста уже будет заниматься ощутимое время.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете решить данную задачу с помощью использования хранимых процедур.

Например так:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spSimil_FirstNameLastName
   @str1 nvarchar(max),
   @threshold float
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT dbo.fnSimil(@str1, Person.Person.FirstName + N' ' +
Person.Person.LastName) AS Simil, * FROM Person.Person) AS T
WHERE T.Simil >= @threshold
ORDER BY T.Simil DESC;
```

Процедура вызывается следующим образом:

```
EXEC dbo.spSimil_FirstNameLastName N'John Adams', 0.75
```

Подробнее можно узнать тут: http://www.accessmvp.com/tomvanstiphout/simil.htm

Для решения вашей задачи можно попробовать прибегнуть к расстояние Левенштейна:
ссылка на реализацию для mysql: https://github.com/ifsnop/damlev

Comment: Спасибо. прочитаю

Comment: Bezarius, в вопросе речь о *mysql*, а не о *ms/sql*.

Comment: Когда задавался вопрос, конкретная бдшка не была указана, и речь о механизме.