# Правильный запрос по поиску пользователей в БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица user (MySQL, InnoDB) с полями id, name и email. Нужно составить грамотный запрос для поиска по таблице с сортировкой по совпадению -- т.е самые точные совпадения сначала, потом менее, менее, и т.д.

Comment: Вы запрашиваете готовое решение? Может, Вы _сами_ попытаетесь сделать хоть что-то? И тогда если не получится - выложите свой код сюда и сообщество Вам поможет?

Comment: по хорошему это умеет только полнотекстовый поиск. Для изобретения велосипеда вам потребуется собственная функция вычисляющая например расстояние Левинштейна, как например здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451355/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-mysql

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/484923/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC/484926#484926

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name as [Имя], email as [Почта] FROM table
ORDER BY name, email
```

Comment: Запрос сначала отсортирует таблицу по имени, потом за электронкой.

Comment: Судя по вопросу ТС ему требуется Не строгий поиск, т.е. поиск похожих и сортировка не по имени, а по степени подобия (как это делают поисковики, когда выдают вам вверху наиболее похожие на ваш запрос сайты)

Comment: у меня в голове только сортировка и крутится)

Answer (score -1):

Оператор LIKE в помощь:

`SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE  'значение%'`

Писал на коленке, но по идее должно работать. :-)

Answer (score -1):

не самый хороший способ, но можно попробовать:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.email 
FROM user 
WHERE users.name ='Игорь' OR users.email ='example@example.com';
```